# How to develop this type of neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, predictive-modeling, matlab

I was given this task to develop, this type of neural network but I never done speech recognition and that type of recognition in Matlab, so could anyone please help and give some help about this task.

Thanks in advance!

[Picture of task](https://ibb.co/Jqvzqbg)

Comment: Basically, you need a speech recognition NN which converts sound to text. Then, an answer is generated to this question and given as the output. Is my intuition correct?

Comment: I think that is true but as I was never done speech recognition paterns I really need help with this. So if you know how is this done to help me?